Error with color name appearing when coloring a node in TikZ
I'm trying to draw a directed graph where each vertex and each arrow can be colored individually by a specific color. I have a code that mostly works:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
       decoration = {markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2mm]}}},
       Bullet/.style = {circle, fill=#1,label=#1,draw=black!80, line width=0.2mm,
       inner sep=2.4pt, node contents={},},
every edge/.style = {draw, postaction=decorate}
                        ]
%
\node (a) at (0,2) [Bullet=red, label=below left:$a$];
\node (b) at (2,4) [Bullet=MidnightBlue, label=above:$b$];
%
\path  
(a) edge [Plum] (b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The problem is that when compiled (using Overleaf) it produces almost what I want, except for also printing the names of the colors of the nodes (vertices) on top of the nodes:

What am I doing wrong that produces this result? How can I remove the color names? Thank you for reading!

For an explanation of the decoration settings, I want the edges to have an arrowhead in the middle (as in the image), and I also want a black outline on the nodes (vertices) which is what I attempted to write in this section as well.

Just get rid of label=#1 in Bullet/.style.

@SandyG, thank you so much!

I’m voting to close this question because because the problem is solved in the comments

I'm voting to first try to convert answering comments into answers instead of closing questions because of an answering comment. See: How to end the "unanswered" status of really solved questions in the comments

As @SandyG already told in a comment, you are using the color name twice in your Bullet/.style once as fill=#1 and second as label=#1. The fill=#1 sets the fill color. The label=#1 outputs the color name as label. So removing the label=#1, solves your issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
       decoration = {markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2mm]}}},
       Bullet/.style = {circle, fill=#1,draw=black!80, line width=0.2mm,
       inner sep=2.4pt, node contents={},},
every edge/.style = {draw, postaction=decorate}
                        ]
%
\node (a) at (0,2) [Bullet=red, label=below left:$a$];
\node (b) at (2,4) [Bullet=MidnightBlue, label=above:$b$];
%
\path  
(a) edge [Plum] (b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



@SandyG I've made this answer instead of asking you to convert your comment into an answer, because there already have been 4 close votes. If you'd like to answer yourself, please do so and I'll vote to delete this one.
